# how can i reset @html.Listbox to empty using jquery in Asp.net MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

@Html.ListBox("project type", new SelectList(db.tblTypes.ToList(), "ID", "Name"), 
                   new { multiple = "multiple", id = "projectType" })

here is my ajax code where i want it to empty

$("#frm").submit(function (e) {

```
                e.preventDefault(e);

             //$('#frm').submit();

             var e = document.getElementById("myselect");

             var selectedIndices = [];
             $(function () {

                 $.each($('select[multiple]'), function (sIndex, sValue) {
                     if (sIndex == 0) {
                         $.each(this.options, function (oIndex, oValue) {
                             if (this.selected)
                                 selectedIndices.push(oIndex);

                         });
                     } else {
                         for (var i = 2; i < selectedIndices.length; i++) {
                             this.options[selectedIndices[i]].selected = true;

                         }
                     }
                 });
             });

             var project = {

                 ProjectTitle: $('#ProjectTitle').val(),
                 ProjectNumber: $('#ProjectNumber').val(),
                 Portfolio: $('#Portfolio').val(),
                 TotalSalesCC: $('#TotalSalesCC').val(),
                 grossMarginCC: $('#GrossMarginCC').val(),


                 projectMarginCC: $('#ProjectMarginCC').val(),
                 projectStatus: e.options[e.selectedIndex].value,
                 ImpStartDate: $('#ImpStartDate').val(),
                 ImpEndDate: $('#ImpEndDate').val(),
                 projectType: selectedIndices,
                 isSurvey:$('#hide').val()

             };

             if ($("#ProjectNumber").val() == "") {
                 $.growl.error({ message: 'Please fill  project number.' });
                 return false;
             }
             if ($("#ProjectTitle").val() == "") {
                 $.growl.error({ message: 'Please fill project title.' });
                 return false;
             }

             if (selectedIndices.length == 0 || selectedIndices.length < 1) {
                 $.growl.error({ message: 'Please choose atleast one project type.' });
                 return false;
             }


             var s=$("#ImpStartDate").val();
             var e = $("#ImpEndDate").val();
             if (s == "" )
             {
                 $.growl.error({ message: 'Please enter start date.' });
                 return false;
             }
             else if (e == "")
             {
                 $.growl.error({ message: 'Please enter end date.' });
                 return false;
             }

             else if (s > e) {
                 $.growl.error({ message: 'End date should be greater than start date.' });
                 return false;
             }

                 var date = new Date();
                 date.setDate(date.getDate()-1);

                 //$('#ImpStartDate').datepicker({
                 //    startDate: date
                 //});





             $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "/Projects/Create",
                 data: JSON.stringify(project),
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 success: function (s) {
                     console.log(s);
                     LoadProjectsGrid();
                     //LoadprojectsGrid();


                     // End For
                     $.growl.notice({ message: ' Your Project created successfuly' });
                     $("#projectType").html('');
                 },
                 failure: function (response) {
                     alert(response.d);
                 }
             });

                 // clear list via dom





                 // or clear list via jquery & dom








             $('#frm').find(".has-success").removeClass("has-success");
             $('#frm').find(".glyphicon-ok").removeClass("glyphicon-ok");
             $('.panel-collapse').collapse('hide');
             $('.panel-title').attr('data-toggle', 'collapse');
             document.getElementById('frm').reset();
             $('#accordion .ui-accordion-content ').hide();








         });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to empty it on the Client side use

```
$("#projectType").html('');
```

And If you want an empty Value on the server side use

```
$("#projectType").val('');
```

Comment: ID is same i want to empty on form submit?

Comment: try `$("#projectType").val('');`

Comment: This is impossible, show the complete Jquery code, how you are calling the above methods?

Comment: $("#frm").submit(function (e) {    $("#projectType").val('');)};

Comment: i ma using it like above

Comment: yes some other functions too but want to reset it in this function

Comment: no i am submitting it via ajax no page reload involved

Comment: something else is stopping the reset please post the complete code in the question.

Comment: move `$("#projectType").html('');` to your ajax success method.

Comment: i am moving it to suceess methid

Comment: I'm sorry in that case there's very less information to give you the desired solution.Make sure the success method is called.Also post the complete code showing your form and the complete jquery so that it's sure that you're not making any other mistake.